# incrementing % value in svg text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the '#perc value increment from 0 to the value in each svg.

Similar to http://builtbybuffalo.com/ with their - a few stats further down the page. I've tried to do it with Javascript and it's just not working, I might try again when it's not 2 in the morning... I digress.

Im very new to javascript/jquery so explanation would be nice as to what to do and why it doesn't work

```js
              function changeText3() {
                var oldHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('perc').innerHTML;
                var intoldHTML = parseInt(oldHTML);
                if (intoldHTML == 0) {
                  intoldHTML += 75;
                }
                return changeText3() + '%';
              }
```

This is the code for the radial percentage circles, the numbers inside are the numbers I want to start at 0 and increase to their values.

```js
var dark = document.getElementsByClassName('dark');
                    var svg = document.getElementsByClassName('svg')[0];
                    var radius = svg.getBBox().width / 2;
                    var t = 0.5,
                        x = 0,
                        y = 0;
                    var theta = {
                        0: 0,
                        1: 0,
                        2: 0
                    };
                    var anims = {}
                    var maxTheta = calcTheta(document.getElementsByClassName('perc'));
                    for (i = 0; i < dark.length; i++) {
                        dark[i].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
                    }

                    function calcTheta(el) {
                        var jbo = {};
                        for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                            jbo[i] = (180 * parseInt(el[i].innerHTML.slice(0, -1), 10)) / 50;
                        }
                        return jbo;
                    }
                    var animOne = setInterval(function() {
                        theta[0] += 0.5;
                        var x = Math.sin(theta[0] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
                        var y = Math.cos(theta[0] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
                        var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[0] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
                        dark[0].setAttribute('d', d);
                        if (theta[0] > maxTheta[0]) {
                            clearInterval(animOne);
                        }
                    }, t);
                    var animTwo = setInterval(function() {
                        theta[1] += 0.5;
                        var x = Math.sin(theta[1] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
                        var y = Math.cos(theta[1] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
                        var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[1] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
                        dark[1].setAttribute('d', d);
                        if (theta[1] > maxTheta[1]) {
                            clearInterval(animTwo);
                        }
                    }, t);
                    var animThree = setInterval(function() {
                        theta[2] += 0.5;
                        var x = Math.sin(theta[2] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
                        var y = Math.cos(theta[2] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
                        var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[2] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
                        dark[2].setAttribute('d', d);
                        if (theta[2] > maxTheta[2]) {
                            clearInterval(animThree);
                        }
                    }, t);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
   <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
   <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
   <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle">0%</text>
    </svg>
    
    
      <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
   <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
   <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
   <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle">0%</text>
  </svg>
    
    <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
   <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
   <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
   <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle">0%</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `perc[N].textContent = Math.round((theta[N]*50)/180) +'%';` into each of your `animN` functions with global `var perc = document.getElementsByClassName('perc');`

```js
var dark = document.getElementsByClassName('dark');
var perc= document.getElementsByClassName('perc');
                    var svg = document.getElementsByClassName('svg')[0];
                    var radius = svg.getBBox().width / 2;
                    var t = 0.5,
                        x = 0,
                        y = 0;
                    var theta = {
                        0: 0,
                        1: 0,
                        2: 0
                    };
                    var anims = {}
                    var maxTheta = calcTheta(perc);
                    for (i = 0; i < dark.length; i++) {
                        dark[i].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
                    }

                    function calcTheta(el) {
                        var jbo = {};
                        for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                            jbo[i] = (180 * parseInt(el[i].innerHTML.slice(0, -1), 10)) / 50;
                        }
                        return jbo;
                    }
                    var animOne = setInterval(function() {
                        theta[0] += 0.5;
                        var x = Math.sin(theta[0] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
                        var y = Math.cos(theta[0] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
                        var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[0] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
                        dark[0].setAttribute('d', d);
                        perc[0].textContent = Math.round((theta[0]*50)/180) +'%';
                        if (theta[0] > maxTheta[0]) {
                            clearInterval(animOne);
                        }
                    }, t);
                    var animTwo = setInterval(function() {
                        theta[1] += 0.5;
                        console.log(theta[1]);
                        var x = Math.sin(theta[1] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
                        var y = Math.cos(theta[1] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
                        var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[1] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
                        dark[1].setAttribute('d', d);
      perc[1].textContent = Math.round((theta[1]*50)/180) +'%';
                        if (theta[1] > maxTheta[1]) {
                            clearInterval(animTwo);
                        }
                    }, t);
                    var animThree = setInterval(function() {
                        theta[2] += 0.5;
                        var x = Math.sin(theta[2] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
                        var y = Math.cos(theta[2] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
                        var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[2] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
                        dark[2].setAttribute('d', d);
      perc[2].textContent = Math.round((theta[2]*50)/180) +'%';
                        if (theta[2] > maxTheta[2]) {
                            clearInterval(animThree);
                        }
                    }, t);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
   <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
   <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
   <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle">75%</text>
    </svg>
    
    
      <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
   <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
   <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
   <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle">9%</text>
  </svg>
    
    <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
   <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
   <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
   <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle">95%</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Edit**
I refactored your function in order to avoid the boiler plate and be able to add as much svg as you want :

```js
var dark, perc, svg, radius;
var t = 0.5, step = 0.5, x = 0, y = 0;
var maxTheta = [], theta=[];


function init(){
 dark = document.getElementsByClassName('dark');
 perc = document.getElementsByClassName('perc');
 svg = document.getElementsByClassName('svg')[0];
 radius = svg.getBBox().width / 2;

 for(i=0; i<perc.length; i++){
  dark[i].setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
  maxTheta[i] = (180 * perc[i].getAttribute('data-perc')) / 50;
  theta[i] = 0;
  anim(i);
  }
 }

var anims = [];
function anim(n) {
 anims[n] = setInterval(function() {
  theta[n] += step;
 
  var x = Math.sin(theta[n] * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
  var y = Math.cos(theta[n] * Math.PI / 180) * -radius;
  var d = 'M0,0 v' + -radius + 'A' + radius + ',' + radius + ' 1 ' + ((theta[n] > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ',1 ' + x + ',' + y + 'z';
 
  dark[n].setAttribute('d', d);
  perc[n].textContent = Math.round((theta[n]*50)/180) +'%';
 
  if (theta[n] > maxTheta[n]) clearInterval(anims[n]);
 
  },t);
 }

init();
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle" data-perc="75"></text>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle" data-perc="9"></text>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle" data-perc="95"></text>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle" data-perc="66"></text>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg" width="33%" height="33%" viewBox="0 0 141 141" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <path class="light" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,140 a70,70 0 1,1 0,-140" fill="#ffb467" />
    <path class="dark" d="M70,70 v-70 a70,70 0 0,1 0,0" fill="#5ab8d4" stroke-colour="#5ab8d4" />
    <path d="M20,70 a50,50 0 0,1 100,0 a50,50 0 0,1 -100,0" fill="white" />
    <text class="perc" x="70" y="79" font-size="2em" text-anchor="middle" data-perc="55"></text>
  </svg>

</div>
```